# How to get Associative Product ID from magento 1.9 using soap api?

Tags: php, soap, magento-1.9

I am creating a wrapper for magento 1.9. I want to use this wrapper to get all configurable products and non-configurable products.

I am using a soap API because when I tried using a REST API I got an authentication error. If you have any idea how to get or see Configurable Product Associated ID by SOAP.